# How do we prove that any smoothing technique is a probability distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we consider any smoothing technique like laplace or delta smoothing. Intuitively we can see that the we are stealing from sequences with non zero probablity and re distribute to sequences with zero probablity and there by it should be a probability distribution function. But how do we prove this mathematically?